# Iterate through poorly formated object

Tags: javascript

I have a really bad-formated javascript object:

```
commits = {
  commit: {
    name: 'First commit'
  },
  commit: {
    name: 'Second commit'
  }
}
```

As you can see, each sub-object of `commits` object is called `commit` so it practically precludes an option to use `for ... in ...` or any other javascript loop (well, that's what i think but i'm a really poor JS programmer so i'm probably wrong). So, the question is, how can i iterate through that object?

Please have in mind that **i can't use jQuery** here and **i can't rewrite that object**

---

**edit:** that object is parsed from the following json:

```
{
  "commits": {
    "commit": {
      "name": "First commit"
    },
    "commit": {
      "name": "Second commit"
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not possible to have two different properties on the same object _with the same name_. So the second one overwrites the first one.

Comment: Yea, that's not a valid object. What's the JSON string?

Comment: oh, sounds legit. Anyway, i'm getting that object from a JSON string so maybe we should start there?

Comment: I suspect commits is an array...

Comment: unfortunately it's not, it's an object obtained from JSON.

Comment: @mbajur: please add the JSON string to your question.

Comment: Post the raw JSON. Where are you getting it from?

Comment: @mbajur Not that way you've written it, it isn't. Maybe you should include the actual object, copy-pasted, instead of trying to type it out. What you've typed out is *impossible* to produce from a JSON string.

Comment: i'm getting that JSON from API of a service i'm using. That json is posted as a raw text and the company knows that it's wrong but they can't do anything about it right now. Anyway, json is posted in original question.

Comment: You need to write your own JSON parser then that can handle this, e.g. by creating new property for each duplicate key so the final output will be something like `commits = { commit1: {
 name: 'First commit' }, commit2: { name: 'Second commit' } }`

Comment: @mbajur: give us the RAW Json string. Don't format it. Give use EXACTLY what the api returns.

Comment: Easier, make an array, each `commit: {...}` in a different case of the array.

Comment: Well, the problem is way more complicated that you can think. The api sends a post request but not with application/json content type but x-www-form-urlencoded type. JSON string has a lot of crap in it, like line breaks and escape chars and i'm allready parsing it myself to remove all of that. Writing my own parser, just like @ShadowWizard suggested sounds as the best solution. I've just thought that i can make it with some build-in methods. Big thanks for your feedback! Upvotes posted :)

Comment: @mbajur no, built in parsers will all fail because unique key is one of JSON's basics. Good luck! :)

Comment: @mbajur: Then something might possibly be going wrong on your end. Writing your own JSON parser may solve the issue, but seems inefficient. I'm very curious about the contents of the raw JSON, now xD
Any way, the real solution would be for the server side to return proper JSON, but as you said, that's not possible :-/

Comment: Do they simply have an alternate format you can consume? Can you get XML out of the same API? That would be preferable to writing your own (broken) JSON parser.

Comment: FYI: here is more or less how my whole process looks like. In provided example there is just one commit in commits object but i think you can see what they did here. @meagar nope, i can't. https://gist.github.com/mbajur/8956798

Comment: @mbajur:
If you add a `}` to the end of the JSON in that link, then wrap the whole string in single quotes (`' ... '`), `JSON.parse()` will actually parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the JSON posted in the [github link](https://gist.github.com/mbajur/8956798) you provided, there's not a lot you have to do.

The JSON string seems to be valid, except that it's missing a `}` at the end of the string. With that fixed, it parses just fine:

```
JSON.parse('{\n  \"accountURL\": \"https://domain.com\",\n  \"newCommitsCount\": \"1\",\n  \"pushURL\":\"https://domain.com/project/64249/git/source/compare/revisions/0b6438955f2a5a7981fd25cfa5b48fe3fb4c888d,7771e638d1356a14d1dc46f3f5cfaab858370a5e\",\n  \"unsubscribeURL\": \"https://domain.com:443/unsubscribe?token=receiverToken&type=COMMITS&projectId=64249\",\n  \"invokerEmail\": \"email@email.com\",\n  \"projectURL\": \"https://domain.com/project/64249\",\n  \"projectId\": \"64249\",\n  \"afterPushRevision\": \"7771e638d1356a14d1dc46f3f5cfaab858370a5e\",\n  \"invokerId\": \"38074\",\n  \"pushDate\": \"2014-02-11T15:26:36+0000\",\n  \"beforePushRevision\": \"0b6438955f2a5a7981fd25cfa5b48fe3fb4c888d\",\n  \"repositoryURL\": \"git_url\",\n  \"subdomain\": \"subdomain\",\n  \"domain\": \"domain\",\n  \"branch\": \"develop\",\n  \"invokerProfileURL\": \"url\",\n  \"commitsCount\": \"1\",\n  \"invokerSmallAvatarURL\": \"xx\",\n  \"projectName\": \"NAME\",\n  \"invoker\": \"Invoker Name.\",\n  \"commits\": {\"commit\":   {\n    \"revision\": \"7771e638d1356a14d1dc46f3f5cfaab858370a5e\",\n    \"commitMessage\": \"quickfix\",\n    \"committerId\": \"38074\",\n    \"committerEmail\": \"email\",\n    \"committerName\": \"Name.\",\n    \"commitDate\": \"2014-02-11T15:26:27+0000\",\n    \"commitURL\": \"https://domain.com/project/64249/git/source/commit/develop/7771e638d1356a14d1dc46f3f5cfaab858370a5e\"  }}}')
```

Comment: wow you're right! I feel really lame right now... and company that produces such horrible JSON string should rot in hell

Comment: @mbajur: Sweet :D Just make sure you double-check if the multiple `commit` properties are parsed properly.
I also hope this illustrates why _raw_ source data can be important in debugging :)